# split a year of data per month (with subplots)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas-groupby, pdfpages

I have a lot of data to analyze, where I want to split it per month. I managed to get a pdf per dataset, but I want to group it per month. Right now I have to split the csv data per month, which is not very efficient. First I make a subplot of the data gathered, where I want to see the amount of timestamps per hour of every day. That is the first for-function.

The second for-function is to create a pdf, where I use the data grouped by hour for grouping. I think I am close, but can't reach the steps to get the result I want.

What I have: A subplot with plots per day of every day in the dataset.
What I need: A subplot with plots per day, one page for every month.
What I want with it?: After this I want to see which days have a value above 15 in a day, isolate those days and put them in one plot with multiple lines.

For now I am trying to get one subplot per month, which makes a pdf for every month. The problem with the subplots is that when I have more than 30 days, the plots become unreadable. Per month it is better to compare.

I tried to put a groupby(pd.grouper(freq= 'M') in two places but it does not work. I let it in to see where I tried it. Maybe a wrong location?

for the dataset:
I had to delete a lot of timestamps due to the limitation of characters. In real it is over 10k timestamps for 2 months.

Thanks in advance.

Dataset to work with:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages 

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os


def plot_to_pdf(dfplot, pdf_name):
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(dfplot.ngroups, figsize=(20,30))

    # instantiate PdfPage Object 
    pp = PdfPages(pdf_name) 

    for i, groupdate in enumerate(dfplot.groups):
        ax=axs[i]
        #the marker is not really necessary but has been added in case there is just one entry per day
        ax.plot(dfplot.get_group(groupdate).Hour, dfplot.get_group(groupdate).Count, color="blue", marker="o")
        ax.plot([0,24], [15, 15], color='red', linestyle='-')
        ax.set_title(str(groupdate))
        ax.set_xlim(0, 24)
        ax.set_ylim(0, maxcount * 1.1)
        ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 25, 2))
    plt.tight_layout()
    pp.savefig(fig)
    pp.close()
    plt.show()
    dfplot.ngroups.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))
#Group your datasets in a single folder
#Can then create a list of all dataset names
filenames = os.listdir("Data/")
# Iterate over a list of datasets
for file_name in filenames:
    #read your data and create datetime index
    df= pd.read_csv('Data/%s' % file_name, sep=";")
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]+df["Time"].str[:-5], format="%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S")
    df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))
```

```css
Date;Time
2020:02:13 ;12:39:02:913 
2020:02:13 ;12:39:42:915 
;
2020:02:13 ;13:06:20:718 
2020:02:13 ;13:18:25:988 
2020:02:13 ;13:34:02:835 
2020:02:13 ;13:46:35:793 
2020:02:13 ;13:59:10:659 
2020:02:13 ;14:14:33:571 
2020:02:13 ;14:25:36:381 
2020:02:13 ;14:35:38:342 
2020:02:13 ;14:46:04:006 
2020:02:13 ;14:56:57:346 
2020:02:13 ;15:07:39:752 

2020:02:20 ;22:12:51:929 
2020:02:20 ;22:13:56:140 
2020:02:20 ;22:14:53:683 
2020:02:20 ;22:15:56:867 
2020:02:20 ;22:16:57:293 
2020:02:20 ;22:17:54:210 
2020:02:20 ;22:18:51:532 
2020:02:20 ;22:19:50:502 
2020:02:20 ;22:20:52:408 
2020:02:20 ;22:21:50:979 
2020:02:20 ;22:22:51:886 
2020:02:20 ;22:23:51:380 
2020:02:20 ;22:24:51:707 
2020:02:20 ;22:25:48:676 
2020:02:20 ;22:26:48:228 
2020:02:20 ;22:27:49:577 
2020:02:20 ;22:28:48:073 
2020:02:20 ;22:29:48:477 
2020:02:20 ;22:30:47:348 
2020:02:20 ;22:31:48:678 
2020:02:20 ;22:32:44:867 
2020:02:20 ;22:33:44:494 
2020:02:20 ;22:34:44:769 
2020:02:20 ;22:35:42:437 
2020:02:20 ;22:36:53:591 
2020:02:20 ;22:37:57:505 
2020:02:20 ;22:39:15:170 
2020:02:20 ;22:40:46:300 
2020:02:20 ;22:42:16:927 
2020:02:20 ;22:43:27:552 
2020:02:20 ;22:44:21:712 
2020:02:20 ;22:45:13:893 
2020:02:20 ;22:46:09:132 
2020:02:20 ;22:47:21:262 
2020:02:20 ;22:48:21:187 
2020:02:20 ;22:49:19:133 
2020:02:20 ;22:50:23:468 
2020:02:20 ;22:51:22:747 
2020:02:20 ;22:52:21:665 
2020:02:20 ;22:53:22:368 
2020:02:20 ;22:54:20:186 
2020:02:20 ;22:55:18:283 
2020:02:20 ;22:56:18:333 
2020:02:20 ;22:57:17:430 


2020:02:27 ;17:22:41:506 
2020:02:27 ;17:25:06:068 

2020:02:27 ;21:10:53:304 
2020:02:27 ;21:12:35:160 
2020:02:27 ;21:14:11:500 
2020:02:27 ;21:15:57:265 
2020:02:27 ;21:17:34:909 
2020:02:27 ;21:19:19:171 
2020:02:27 ;21:20:55:487 
2020:02:27 ;21:22:40:174 
2020:02:27 ;21:24:16:921 
2020:02:27 ;21:26:00:376 
2020:02:27 ;21:27:38:020 
2020:02:27 ;21:29:19:975 
2020:02:27 ;21:30:55:920 
2020:02:27 ;21:32:41:079 
2020:02:27 ;21:34:18:323 
2020:02:27 ;21:35:57:772 
2020:02:27 ;21:37:33:014 
2020:02:27 ;21:39:16:370 
2020:02:27 ;21:40:52:210 
2020:02:27 ;21:42:31:358 
2020:02:27 ;21:44:06:195 
2020:02:27 ;21:45:42:337 
2020:02:27 ;21:47:14:266 
2020:02:27 ;21:48:55:721 
2020:02:27 ;21:50:34:769 
2020:02:27 ;21:52:07:802 
2020:02:27 ;21:53:48:053 
2020:02:27 ;21:55:23:821 
2020:02:27 ;21:56:58:530 
2020:02:27 ;21:58:33:793 
2020:02:27 ;22:00:06:552 
2020:02:27 ;22:01:40:637 
2020:02:27 ;22:03:12:016 
2020:02:27 ;22:04:43:795 
2020:02:27 ;22:06:14:523 
2020:02:27 ;22:07:49:260 
2020:02:27 ;22:09:23:396 
2020:02:27 ;22:10:56:429 
2020:02:27 ;22:12:26:254 
2020:02:27 ;22:14:01:192 
2020:02:27 ;22:15:34:927 
2020:02:27 ;22:17:07:082 
2020:02:27 ;22:18:31:970 
2020:02:27 ;22:20:06:810 
2020:02:27 ;22:21:54:477 
2020:02:27 ;22:24:14:829 
2020:02:27 ;22:26:49:516 
2020:02:27 ;22:28:48:314 
2020:02:27 ;22:30:22:250 
2020:02:27 ;22:31:56:489 
2020:02:27 ;22:33:31:327 
2020:02:27 ;22:35:04:456 
2020:02:27 ;22:36:40:096 
2020:02:27 ;22:38:11:074 
2020:02:27 ;22:39:44:358 
2020:02:27 ;22:41:17:090 
2020:02:27 ;22:42:51:125 
2020:02:27 ;22:44:21:606 
2020:02:27 ;22:45:33:131 
2020:02:27 ;22:45:33:131 
2020:02:27 ;22:47:20:103 
2020:03:01 ;16:36:10:647 
2020:03:01 ;16:36:46:036 
2020:03:01 ;16:39:37:968 
2020:03:01 ;16:42:48:947 
2020:03:01 ;16:45:22:735 
2020:03:01 ;16:47:07:394 
2020:03:01 ;16:48:59:577 
2020:03:01 ;16:51:00:177 
2020:03:01 ;16:52:48:047 
2020:03:01 ;16:54:46:544 
2020:03:01 ;16:56:39:828 
2020:03:01 ;16:58:32:811 
2020:03:01 ;17:00:33:012 
2020:03:01 ;17:02:22:386 
2020:03:01 ;17:04:22:787 
2020:03:01 ;17:06:20:182 
2020:03:01 ;17:08:12:340 
2020:03:01 ;17:10:11:887 
2020:03:01 ;17:12:12:063 
2020:03:01 ;17:14:19:181 
2020:03:01 ;17:16:22:791 
2020:03:01 ;17:18:29:508 
2020:03:01 ;17:20:36:427 
2020:03:01 ;17:22:34:447 
2020:03:01 ;17:24:38:533 
2020:03:01 ;17:26:42:443 
2020:03:01 ;17:28:52:697 
2020:03:01 ;17:31:04:901 
2020:03:01 ;17:33:18:010 
2020:03:01 ;17:35:34:628 
2020:03:01 ;17:38:09:465 
2020:03:01 ;17:41:14:453 
2020:03:01 ;17:44:38:040 
2020:03:01 ;17:48:17:588 
2020:03:01 ;17:52:16:987 
2020:03:01 ;17:56:30:723 
2020:03:01 ;18:00:49:672 
2020:03:01 ;18:05:12:632 
2020:03:01 ;18:09:38:696 
2020:03:01 ;18:13:56:944 
2020:03:01 ;18:18:07:772 
2020:03:01 ;18:21:59:552 
2020:03:01 ;18:25:29:579 
2020:03:01 ;18:29:00:206 
2020:03:01 ;18:32:47:676 
2020:03:01 ;18:36:53:592 
2020:03:01 ;18:41:35:899 
2020:03:01 ;18:46:17:204 
2020:03:01 ;18:50:33:045 
2020:03:01 ;18:54:40:765 
2020:03:01 ;18:58:45:979 
2020:03:01 ;19:02:48:667 
2020:03:01 ;19:06:44:579 
2020:03:01 ;19:10:45:382 
2020:03:01 ;19:14:40:475 
2020:03:01 ;19:18:35:614 
2020:03:01 ;19:22:33:157 
2020:03:01 ;19:26:27:366 
2020:03:01 ;19:30:15:112 
2020:03:01 ;19:33:59:077 
2020:03:01 ;19:37:37:771 
2020:03:01 ;19:41:22:984 
2020:03:01 ;19:45:01:234 
2020:03:01 ;19:48:38:628 
2020:03:01 ;19:52:13:013 
2020:03:01 ;19:55:40:134 
2020:03:01 ;19:59:16:578 
2020:03:01 ;20:02:44:595 
2020:03:01 ;20:06:15:122 
2020:03:01 ;20:09:45:328 
2020:03:01 ;20:13:07:056 
2020:03:01 ;20:16:29:062 
2020:03:01 ;20:19:44:954 
2020:03:01 ;20:23:08:365 
2020:03:01 ;20:26:26:758 
2020:03:01 ;20:29:42:949 
2020:03:01 ;20:32:48:865 
2020:03:01 ;20:35:54:279 
2020:03:01 ;20:39:10:972 
2020:03:01 ;20:42:44:607 
2020:03:01 ;20:46:27:970 
2020:03:01 ;20:49:41:452 
2020:03:01 ;20:52:52:830 
2020:03:01 ;20:56:08:826 
2020:03:01 ;20:59:21:505 
2020:03:01 ;21:02:21:857 
2020:03:01 ;21:05:06:068 
2020:03:01 ;21:08:14:568 
2020:03:01 ;21:10:52:034 
2020:03:01 ;21:13:33:038 
2020:03:01 ;21:16:12:437 
2020:03:01 ;21:18:50:834 
2020:03:01 ;21:21:26:925 
2020:03:01 ;21:24:11:136 
2020:03:01 ;21:26:49:887 
2020:03:01 ;21:29:27:328 
2020:03:01 ;21:32:03:820 
2020:03:01 ;21:34:41:645 
2020:03:01 ;21:37:15:100 
2020:03:01 ;21:39:49:386 
2020:03:01 ;21:42:23:673 
2020:03:01 ;21:44:57:758 
2020:03:01 ;21:47:33:150 
2020:03:01 ;21:50:02:121 
2020:03:01 ;21:52:33:304 
2020:03:01 ;21:55:08:589 
2020:03:01 ;21:57:40:169 
2020:03:01 ;22:00:08:942 
2020:03:01 ;22:02:37:914 
2020:03:01 ;22:05:08:946 
2020:03:01 ;22:07:40:773 
2020:03:01 ;22:10:11:354 
2020:03:01 ;22:12:36:714 
2020:03:01 ;22:15:00:476 
2020:03:01 ;22:17:25:690 
2020:03:01 ;22:19:50:902 
2020:03:01 ;22:22:12:109 
2020:03:01 ;22:24:34:011 
2020:03:01 ;22:26:59:876 
2020:03:01 ;22:29:25:543 
2020:03:01 ;22:31:47:397 
2020:03:01 ;22:34:05:593 
2020:03:01 ;22:36:26:773 
2020:03:01 ;22:38:50:456 
2020:03:01 ;22:41:20:834 
2020:03:01 ;22:44:23:190 
2020:03:01 ;22:47:36:774 
2020:03:01 ;22:50:15:773 
2020:03:01 ;22:52:39:886 
2020:03:01 ;22:55:06:602 
2020:03:01 ;22:57:35:475 
2020:03:01 ;22:59:57:330 
2020:03:01 ;23:02:18:484 
2020:03:01 ;23:04:46:555 
2020:03:01 ;23:07:07:408 
2020:03:01 ;23:09:28:762 
2020:03:01 ;23:11:46:633 
2020:03:01 ;23:14:03:349 
2020:03:01 ;23:16:18:187 
2020:03:01 ;23:18:34:604 
2020:03:01 ;23:20:47:665 
2020:03:01 ;23:23:00:795 
2020:03:01 ;23:25:13:829 
2020:03:01 ;23:27:24:657 
2020:03:01 ;23:29:37:991 
2020:03:01 ;23:31:51:229 
2020:03:01 ;23:34:04:359 
2020:03:01 ;23:36:17:191 
2020:03:01 ;23:38:30:625 
2020:03:01 ;23:40:43:458 
2020:03:01 ;23:42:56:491 
2020:03:01 ;23:45:09:328 
2020:03:01 ;23:47:17:044 
2020:03:01 ;23:49:28:372 
2020:03:01 ;23:51:34:087 
2020:03:01 ;23:53:42:008 
2020:03:01 ;23:55:47:522 
2020:03:01 ;23:57:50:831 
2020:03:01 ;23:59:51:333 
2020:03:02 ;00:01:51:534 
2020:03:02 ;00:03:53:440 
2020:03:02 ;00:05:53:641 
2020:03:02 ;00:07:54:220 
2020:03:02 ;00:09:55:948 
2020:03:02 ;00:11:59:757 
2020:03:02 ;00:14:01:463 
2020:03:02 ;00:15:58:355 
2020:03:02 ;00:18:00:462 

2020:03:02 ;03:45:02:979 
2020:03:02 ;03:46:39:020 
2020:03:02 ;03:48:12:955 
2020:03:02 ;03:49:53:908 
2020:03:02 ;03:51:28:646 
2020:03:02 ;03:53:03:784 
2020:03:02 ;03:54:41:328 
2020:03:02 ;03:56:14:964 
2020:03:02 ;03:57:53:710 
2020:03:02 ;03:59:30:256 
2020:03:02 ;04:01:02:684 
2020:03:02 ;04:02:44:639 
2020:03:02 ;04:04:17:472 
2020:03:02 ;04:05:53:011 
2020:03:02 ;04:07:25:948 
2020:03:02 ;04:08:59:077 
2020:03:02 ;04:10:33:614 
2020:03:02 ;04:12:07:650 
2020:03:02 ;04:13:38:276 
2020:03:02 ;04:15:09:003 
2020:03:02 ;04:16:40:232 
2020:03:02 ;04:18:11:160 
2020:03:02 ;04:19:40:985 
2020:03:02 ;04:21:12:815 
2020:03:02 ;04:22:43:442 
2020:03:02 ;04:24:18:079 
2020:03:02 ;04:25:45:097 
2020:03:02 ;04:27:16:426 
2020:03:02 ;04:28:47:654 
2020:03:02 ;04:30:17:279 
2020:03:02 ;04:31:45:199 
2020:03:02 ;04:33:16:129 
2020:03:02 ;04:34:46:206 
2020:03:02 ;04:36:11:867 
2020:03:02 ;04:37:41:291 
2020:03:02 ;04:39:08:109 
2020:03:02 ;04:40:33:923 
2020:03:02 ;04:42:00:140 
2020:03:02 ;04:43:27:612 
2020:03:02 ;04:44:53:278 
2020:03:02 ;04:46:20:190 
2020:03:02 ;04:47:46:307 
2020:03:02 ;04:49:24:152 
2020:03:02 ;04:51:49:516 

2020:03:02 ;05:25:31:080 
2020:03:02 ;05:26:55:368 
2020:03:02 ;05:28:21:206 
2020:03:02 ;05:29:44:915 
2020:03:02 ;05:31:09:631 
2020:03:02 ;05:32:31:934 
2020:03:02 ;05:33:51:834 
2020:03:02 ;05:35:19:253 
2020:03:02 ;05:36:41:158 
2020:03:02 ;05:38:05:771 
2020:03:02 ;05:39:30:182 
2020:03:02 ;05:40:54:898 
2020:03:02 ;05:42:15:797 
2020:03:02 ;05:43:43:616 
2020:03:02 ;05:45:04:519 
2020:03:02 ;05:46:30:133 
2020:03:02 ;05:47:46:425 
2020:03:02 ;05:49:06:827 
2020:03:02 ;05:50:28:531 
2020:03:02 ;05:51:48:534 
2020:03:02 ;05:53:12:772 
2020:03:02 ;05:54:37:055 
2020:03:02 ;05:56:01:268 
2020:03:02 ;05:57:18:057 
2020:03:02 ;05:58:37:331 
2020:03:02 ;05:59:55:555 
2020:03:02 ;06:01:11:642 
2020:03:02 ;06:02:30:239 
2020:03:02 ;06:03:50:716 
2020:03:02 ;06:05:10:995 
2020:03:02 ;06:06:27:934 
2020:03:02 ;06:07:45:729 
2020:03:02 ;06:09:00:819 
2020:03:02 ;06:10:18:412 
2020:03:02 ;06:11:34:101 
2020:03:02 ;06:12:49:791 
2020:03:02 ;06:14:06:382 
2020:03:02 ;06:15:23:727 
2020:03:02 ;06:16:41:975 
2020:03:02 ;06:17:57:462 
2020:03:02 ;06:19:14:054 
2020:03:02 ;06:20:30:846 
2020:03:02 ;06:21:43:728 
2020:03:02 ;06:22:59:446 

2020:03:12 ;19:40:26:766 
2020:03:12 ;19:47:56:993 
2020:03:12 ;19:55:48:978 
2020:03:12 ;20:03:50:382 
2020:03:12 ;20:12:00:610 
2020:03:12 ;20:20:12:968 
2020:03:12 ;20:28:27:381 
2020:03:12 ;20:36:50:742 
2020:03:12 ;20:45:15:908 
2020:03:12 ;20:53:52:903 
2020:03:12 ;21:01:29:647 
2020:03:12 ;21:09:40:176 
2020:03:12 ;21:18:05:642 
2020:03:12 ;21:25:02:987 
2020:03:12 ;21:32:30:809 
2020:03:12 ;21:40:24:095 
2020:03:12 ;21:48:34:423 
2020:03:12 ;21:57:04:605 
2020:03:12 ;22:05:45:707 
2020:03:12 ;22:14:37:238 
2020:03:12 ;22:23:33:385 
2020:03:12 ;22:32:39:854 
2020:03:12 ;22:41:55:241 
2020:03:12 ;22:51:22:562 
2020:03:12 ;22:59:09:231 
2020:03:12 ;23:07:24:900 
2020:03:12 ;23:15:47:158 
2020:03:12 ;23:25:00:918 
2020:03:12 ;23:34:56:209 
2020:03:12 ;23:44:48:895 
2020:03:12 ;23:54:28:345 
2020:03:13 ;00:02:12:512 
2020:03:13 ;07:53:04:478 
2020:03:13 ;07:53:40:869 
2020:03:13 ;08:01:39:469 
2020:03:13 ;08:11:45:788 
2020:03:13 ;12:03:11:972 
2020:03:13 ;12:03:48:565 
2020:03:13 ;12:18:40:699 
2020:03:13 ;12:37:41:206 
2020:03:13 ;12:56:30:234 
2020:03:13 ;13:14:14:979 
2020:03:13 ;13:30:57:116 
2020:03:13 ;13:48:12:485 
2020:03:13 ;14:05:39:729 
2020:03:13 ;14:24:56:326 
2020:03:13 ;14:45:30:222 
2020:03:13 ;15:07:25:913 
2020:03:13 ;15:18:12:437 
2020:03:13 ;15:35:00:457 
2020:03:13 ;15:53:04:974 
2020:03:13 ;16:01:27:586 
2020:03:14 ;11:08:24:518 
2020:03:14 ;11:09:02:113 
2020:03:14 ;11:51:43:053 
2020:03:14 ;12:24:50:807 
2020:03:14 ;12:38:58:504 
2020:03:14 ;12:50:40:637 
2020:03:14 ;12:59:41:418 
2020:03:14 ;13:09:48:538 
2020:03:14 ;13:19:21:976 
2020:03:14 ;13:29:35:110 
2020:03:14 ;13:40:10:903 
2020:03:14 ;13:51:48:250 
2020:03:14 ;14:04:43:191 
2020:03:14 ;14:19:14:323 
2020:03:14 ;14:32:30:393 
2020:03:14 ;14:41:41:748 
2020:03:14 ;14:51:12:378 
2020:03:14 ;15:03:28:347 
2020:03:14 ;15:14:48:525 
2020:03:14 ;15:26:48:730 
2020:03:14 ;15:39:43:670 
2020:03:14 ;15:53:21:473 
2020:03:14 ;16:08:37:013 
2020:03:14 ;16:23:25:163 
2020:03:14 ;16:37:40:079 
2020:03:14 ;16:52:37:831 
2020:03:14 ;17:04:13:373 
2020:03:14 ;17:16:17:283 
2020:03:14 ;17:28:41:949 
2020:03:14 ;17:40:22:381 
2020:03:14 ;17:54:22:211 
2020:03:14 ;18:09:23:264 
2020:03:14 ;18:26:28:132 
2020:03:14 ;18:43:04:228 
2020:03:14 ;18:59:42:026 
2020:03:14 ;19:16:49:902 

2020:03:16 ;21:16:35:082 
2020:03:16 ;21:25:56:990 
2020:03:16 ;21:33:33:033 
2020:03:16 ;21:41:34:343 
2020:03:16 ;21:50:27:874 
2020:03:16 ;21:59:22:814 
2020:03:16 ;22:08:52:040 
2020:03:16 ;22:18:49:211 
2020:03:16 ;22:29:24:828 
2020:03:16 ;22:39:17:714 
2020:03:16 ;22:48:15:361 
2020:03:16 ;22:55:47:994 
2020:03:16 ;23:04:30:829 
2020:03:16 ;23:13:25:844 
2020:03:16 ;23:22:29:305 
2020:03:16 ;23:32:16:577 
2020:03:16 ;23:36:41:841 
2020:03:17 ;13:57:04:232 
2020:03:17 ;13:57:39:220 
2020:03:17 ;14:09:25:590 
2020:03:17 ;14:19:32:010 
2020:03:17 ;14:32:40:786 
2020:03:17 ;14:46:03:095 
2020:03:17 ;15:01:07:864 
2020:03:17 ;15:18:50:223 
2020:03:17 ;15:34:27:371 
2020:03:17 ;15:49:36:448 
2020:03:17 ;16:05:53:600 
2020:03:17 ;16:16:58:261 
2020:03:17 ;16:24:53:953 
2020:03:17 ;16:34:43:830 
2020:03:17 ;16:48:57:869 
2020:03:17 ;16:56:12:758 
2020:03:17 ;17:06:48:852 
2020:03:17 ;17:19:21:838 
2020:03:17 ;17:33:02:797 
2020:03:17 ;17:48:00:999 
2020:03:17 ;18:01:09:721 
2020:03:17 ;18:14:33:033 
2020:03:17 ;18:27:23:462 
2020:03:17 ;18:39:02:914 
2020:03:17 ;18:51:34:699 
2020:03:17 ;19:04:22:149 
2020:03:17 ;19:16:27:638 
2020:03:17 ;19:29:54:459 
2020:03:17 ;19:45:10:153 
2020:03:17 ;20:02:14:519 
2020:03:17 ;20:15:46:953 
2020:03:17 ;20:29:25:684 
2020:03:17 ;20:44:15:935 
2020:03:17 ;20:59:56:992 
2020:03:17 ;21:14:56:244 
2020:03:17 ;21:26:53:641 
2020:03:17 ;21:40:04:125 
2020:03:17 ;21:54:38:412 
2020:03:17 ;22:10:55:259 
2020:03:17 ;22:27:25:239 
2020:03:17 ;22:41:25:950 
2020:03:17 ;22:55:39:383 
2020:03:17 ;23:07:33:075 
2020:03:18 ;16:53:46:824 
2020:03:18 ;16:54:22:313 
2020:03:18 ;17:04:40:661 
2020:03:18 ;17:23:21:069 
2020:03:18 ;17:42:51:601 
2020:03:18 ;18:03:25:993 
2020:03:18 ;18:28:43:597 
2020:03:18 ;18:50:16:934 
2020:03:18 ;19:11:37:896 
2020:03:18 ;19:36:16:673 
2020:03:18 ;20:00:31:041 
2020:03:18 ;20:17:48:141 
2020:03:18 ;20:38:27:593 
2020:03:18 ;21:01:35:570 
2020:03:18 ;21:19:36:678 
2020:03:18 ;21:42:29:768 
2020:03:18 ;22:09:56:443 
2020:03:18 ;22:29:37:000 
2020:03:19 ;14:36:27:970 
2020:03:19 ;14:37:01:754 
2020:03:19 ;15:02:30:484 
2020:03:19 ;15:36:27:487 
2020:03:19 ;16:11:44:389 
2020:03:19 ;16:48:22:520 
2020:03:19 ;17:25:44:866 
2020:03:19 ;17:41:39:504 
2020:03:20 ;13:29:18:703 
2020:03:20 ;13:29:54:795 
2020:03:20 ;13:38:06:928 
2020:03:20 ;13:47:15:905 
2020:03:20 ;14:00:13:050 
2020:03:20 ;14:12:22:276 
2020:03:20 ;14:24:59:373 
2020:03:20 ;14:39:12:787 
2020:03:20 ;14:55:14:322 
2020:03:20 ;15:06:40:542 
2020:03:20 ;15:14:09:392 
2020:03:20 ;15:24:56:483 
2020:03:20 ;15:37:06:311 
2020:03:20 ;15:50:10:476 
2020:03:20 ;16:04:34:640 
2020:03:20 ;16:21:37:205 
2020:03:20 ;16:34:37:858 
2020:03:20 ;16:48:11:998 
2020:03:20 ;17:02:10:398 
2020:03:20 ;17:12:36:766 
2020:03:20 ;17:23:23:688 
2020:03:20 ;17:25:00:733 
2020:03:21 ;11:02:40:796 
2020:03:21 ;11:03:16:585 
2020:03:21 ;11:10:30:774 
2020:03:21 ;11:17:01:453 
2020:03:21 ;11:23:31:029 
2020:03:21 ;11:28:49:627 
2020:03:21 ;11:34:09:127 
2020:03:21 ;11:39:26:422 
2020:03:21 ;11:44:45:922 
2020:03:21 ;11:50:03:522 
2020:03:21 ;11:55:03:970 
2020:03:21 ;11:58:58:057 
2020:03:21 ;12:03:24:424 
2020:03:21 ;12:08:16:358 
2020:03:21 ;12:13:05:379 

2020:03:23 ;14:34:49:012 
2020:03:23 ;14:42:27:764 
2020:03:23 ;14:50:31:472 
2020:03:23 ;14:58:56:638 
2020:03:23 ;15:07:35:015 
2020:03:23 ;15:16:37:295 
2020:03:23 ;15:23:12:885 
2020:03:23 ;15:30:43:013 
2020:03:23 ;15:37:18:103 
2020:03:23 ;15:44:28:983 
2020:03:23 ;15:52:16:254 
2020:03:23 ;16:00:02:321 
2020:03:23 ;16:07:48:688 
2020:03:23 ;16:16:02:627 
2020:03:23 ;16:24:33:607 
2020:03:23 ;16:33:21:279 
2020:03:23 ;16:42:38:924 
2020:03:23 ;16:50:13:764 
2020:03:23 ;16:56:36:626 
2020:03:23 ;17:03:33:467 
2020:03:23 ;17:10:57:131 
2020:03:23 ;17:18:31:065 
2020:03:23 ;17:26:29:918 
2020:03:23 ;17:34:25:607 
2020:03:23 ;17:42:29:318 
2020:03:23 ;17:50:32:329 
2020:03:23 ;17:58:42:106 
2020:03:23 ;18:07:13:236 
2020:03:23 ;18:14:59:604 
2020:03:23 ;18:22:10:583 
2020:03:23 ;18:30:04:270 
2020:03:23 ;18:38:46:578 
2020:03:23 ;18:47:40:519 
2020:03:23 ;18:55:51:847 
2020:03:23 ;19:03:24:781 
2020:03:23 ;19:11:23:782 
2020:03:23 ;19:19:26:591 
2020:03:23 ;19:27:27:449 
2020:03:23 ;19:35:28:200 
2020:03:23 ;19:43:17:876 
2020:03:23 ;19:50:02:189 
2020:03:23 ;19:57:21:890 
2020:03:23 ;20:04:59:265 
2020:03:23 ;20:12:50:517 
2020:03:23 ;20:20:43:401 
2020:03:23 ;20:28:42:505 
2020:03:23 ;20:36:42:708 
2020:03:23 ;20:44:55:138 
2020:03:23 ;20:53:17:395 
2020:03:23 ;21:00:26:271 

2020:03:24 ;20:06:56:612 
2020:03:24 ;20:14:19:923 
2020:03:24 ;20:21:49:976 
2020:03:24 ;20:29:20:279 
2020:03:24 ;20:36:53:915 
2020:03:24 ;20:43:43:766 
2020:03:24 ;20:49:47:152 
2020:03:24 ;20:56:32:019 
2020:03:24 ;21:03:34:825 
2020:03:24 ;21:10:44:206 
2020:03:24 ;21:17:55:982 
2020:03:24 ;21:25:04:456 
2020:03:24 ;21:32:27:466 
2020:03:24 ;21:39:44:889 
2020:03:24 ;21:47:04:964 
2020:03:24 ;21:54:26:599 
2020:03:24 ;22:01:45:871 
2020:03:24 ;22:07:40:058 
2020:03:24 ;22:14:10:939 
2020:03:24 ;22:20:52:042 
2020:03:24 ;22:27:37:156 
2020:03:24 ;22:34:50:040 
2020:03:24 ;22:42:04:733 
2020:03:24 ;22:49:29:272 
2020:03:24 ;22:57:08:697 
2020:03:24 ;23:04:59:272 
2020:03:24 ;23:07:53:910 
2020:03:25 ;08:46:27:868 
2020:03:25 ;08:47:04:259 
2020:03:25 ;08:54:24:162 
2020:03:25 ;09:04:19:854 
2020:03:25 ;09:14:23:065 
2020:03:25 ;09:24:14:948 
2020:03:25 ;09:34:10:339 
2020:03:25 ;09:44:10:445 
2020:03:25 ;09:54:12:453 
2020:03:25 ;10:04:26:989 
2020:03:25 ;10:14:40:928 
2020:03:25 ;10:24:55:968 
2020:03:25 ;10:33:21:840 
2020:03:25 ;10:39:45:396 
2020:03:25 ;10:49:05:199 
2020:03:25 ;10:57:06:307 
2020:03:25 ;11:05:27:635 
2020:03:25 ;11:13:03:902 
2020:03:25 ;11:20:27:513 
2020:03:25 ;11:27:35:890 
2020:03:25 ;11:34:37:142 
2020:03:26 ;11:53:48:330 
2020:03:26 ;11:59:11:841 
2020:03:26 ;12:02:54:202 
2020:03:26 ;12:07:29:488 
2020:03:26 ;12:12:28:164 
2020:03:26 ;12:17:38:814 
2020:03:26 ;12:23:06:334 
2020:03:26 ;12:28:31:027 
2020:03:26 ;12:34:02:006 
2020:03:26 ;12:39:36:013 
2020:03:26 ;12:45:19:502 
2020:03:26 ;12:51:04:843 
2020:03:26 ;12:56:54:114 

2020:03:28 ;07:40:15:536 
2020:03:28 ;07:44:25:963 
2020:03:28 ;07:48:41:203 
2020:03:28 ;07:53:06:391 
2020:03:28 ;07:57:32:534 
2020:03:28 ;08:01:56:097 
2020:03:28 ;08:06:21:157 
2020:03:28 ;08:10:40:207 
2020:03:28 ;08:15:08:077 
2020:03:28 ;08:19:42:966 
2020:03:28 ;08:24:18:408 
2020:03:28 ;08:28:31:591 
2020:03:28 ;08:32:38:639 
2020:03:28 ;08:36:58:460 
2020:03:28 ;08:41:20:416 
2020:03:28 ;08:45:49:719 
2020:03:28 ;08:50:11:847 
2020:03:28 ;08:54:28:093 
2020:03:28 ;08:58:36:512 
2020:03:28 ;09:02:51:951 
2020:03:28 ;09:07:05:487 
2020:03:28 ;09:11:27:142 
2020:03:28 ;09:15:48:197 
2020:03:28 ;09:20:00:154 
2020:03:28 ;09:24:22:384 
2020:03:28 ;09:28:50:555 
2020:03:28 ;09:33:05:495 
2020:03:28 ;09:37:18:854 
2020:03:28 ;09:41:41:915 
2020:03:28 ;09:45:48:204 

2020:03:28 ;22:06:39:505 
2020:03:28 ;22:10:28:579 
2020:03:28 ;22:14:20:563 
2020:03:28 ;22:18:10:034 
2020:03:28 ;22:21:57:107 
2020:03:28 ;22:25:51:315 
2020:03:28 ;22:29:50:390 
2020:03:28 ;22:33:44:475 
2020:03:28 ;22:37:31:143 
2020:03:28 ;22:41:19:014 
2020:03:28 ;22:44:59:868 
2020:03:28 ;22:48:45:182 
2020:03:28 ;22:52:35:610 
2020:03:28 ;22:56:31:500 
2020:03:28 ;23:00:30:599 
2020:03:28 ;23:04:29:698 
2020:03:28 ;23:08:27:594 

2020:03:29 ;12:13:28:749 
2020:03:29 ;12:15:59:526 
2020:03:29 ;12:18:29:000 
2020:03:29 ;12:21:02:485 
2020:03:29 ;12:23:37:699 
2020:03:29 ;12:26:12:562 
2020:03:29 ;12:28:48:553 
2020:03:29 ;12:31:20:485 
2020:03:29 ;12:33:43:846 
2020:03:29 ;12:36:10:060 
2020:03:29 ;12:38:42:240 
2020:03:29 ;12:41:21:739 
2020:03:29 ;12:43:56:527 
2020:03:29 ;12:46:10:362 
2020:03:29 ;12:48:39:336 
2020:03:29 ;12:51:07:936 
2020:03:29 ;12:53:44:475 
2020:03:29 ;12:56:19:115 
2020:03:29 ;12:58:48:787 
2020:03:29 ;13:01:25:154 
2020:03:29 ;13:04:00:872 
2020:03:29 ;13:06:39:745 
2020:03:29 ;13:09:15:231 
2020:03:29 ;13:11:56:538 
2020:03:29 ;13:14:37:238 
2020:03:29 ;13:17:18:995 
2020:03:29 ;13:20:02:653 
2020:03:29 ;13:22:50:975 
2020:03:29 ;13:25:34:484 
2020:03:29 ;13:28:21:703 
2020:03:29 ;13:31:09:122 
2020:03:29 ;13:33:54:337 
2020:03:29 ;13:36:27:520 
2020:03:29 ;13:39:09:827 
2020:03:29 ;13:42:01:557 
2020:03:29 ;13:44:46:169 
2020:03:29 ;13:47:31:282 
2020:03:29 ;13:50:19:704 
2020:03:29 ;13:53:18:779 
2020:03:29 ;13:56:04:668 
2020:03:29 ;13:58:45:872 
2020:03:29 ;14:01:31:087 
2020:03:29 ;14:04:09:884 
2020:03:29 ;14:06:50:085 
2020:03:29 ;14:09:39:409 
2020:03:29 ;14:12:22:320 
2020:03:29 ;14:15:14:148 
2020:03:29 ;14:18:02:871 
2020:03:29 ;14:20:54:401 
2020:03:29 ;14:23:46:532 
2020:03:29 ;14:26:42:673 
2020:03:29 ;14:29:40:218 
2020:03:29 ;14:32:35:958 
2020:03:29 ;14:35:34:405 
2020:03:29 ;14:38:32:977 
2020:03:29 ;14:41:37:013 
2020:03:29 ;14:44:42:077 
2020:03:29 ;14:47:46:038 
2020:03:29 ;14:50:53:307 
2020:03:29 ;14:53:45:137 
2020:03:29 ;14:56:46:190 
2020:03:29 ;14:59:48:247 
2020:03:29 ;15:02:47:721 
2020:03:29 ;15:05:48:277 
2020:03:29 ;15:08:51:207 
2020:03:29 ;15:11:53:664 
2020:03:29 ;15:14:58:301 
2020:03:29 ;15:17:53:966 
2020:03:29 ;15:20:47:701 
2020:03:29 ;15:23:55:371 

2020:03:29 ;20:36:41:380 
2020:03:29 ;20:40:24:745 
2020:03:29 ;20:44:11:107 
2020:03:29 ;20:47:57:674 
2020:03:29 ;20:51:41:339 
2020:03:29 ;20:55:22:790 
2020:03:29 ;20:59:07:152 
2020:03:29 ;21:02:50:711 
2020:03:29 ;21:06:34:600 
2020:03:29 ;21:10:11:469 
2020:03:29 ;21:13:47:159 
2020:03:29 ;21:17:17:885 
2020:03:29 ;21:20:56:832 
2020:03:29 ;21:24:42:929 
2020:03:29 ;21:28:22:348 
2020:03:29 ;21:32:11:422 
2020:03:29 ;21:35:55:082 
2020:03:29 ;21:39:39:444 
2020:03:29 ;21:43:19:396 
2020:03:29 ;21:47:02:153 
2020:03:29 ;21:50:44:964 
2020:03:29 ;21:54:19:248 
2020:03:29 ;21:58:06:622 
2020:03:29 ;22:01:46:468 
2020:03:29 ;22:05:27:923 
2020:03:29 ;22:09:09:278 
2020:03:29 ;22:12:55:545 
2020:03:29 ;22:16:38:303 
2020:03:29 ;22:20:21:662 
2020:03:29 ;22:24:05:423 
2020:03:29 ;22:27:47:078 
2020:03:29 ;22:31:31:946 
2020:03:29 ;22:35:16:103 
2020:03:29 ;22:38:54:851 
2020:03:29 ;22:42:30:696 
2020:03:29 ;22:46:11:745 
2020:03:29 ;22:49:54:654 
2020:03:29 ;22:53:37:963 
2020:03:29 ;22:57:17:715 
2020:03:29 ;23:00:59:770 
2020:03:29 ;23:04:39:748 
2020:03:29 ;23:08:14:459 
2020:03:29 ;23:11:59:021 
2020:03:29 ;23:15:42:358 
2020:03:29 ;23:19:26:321 
2020:03:29 ;23:23:09:354 
2020:03:29 ;23:26:46:043 
2020:03:29 ;23:30:26:696 
2020:03:29 ;23:34:07:147 
2020:03:29 ;23:37:50:307 
2020:03:29 ;23:41:30:262 
2020:03:29 ;23:45:06:700 
2020:03:29 ;23:48:46:050 
2020:03:29 ;23:52:25:599
```

Comment: If I've understood your question correctly, I think you might be looking for df.resample('M') which will resample the datetime into months.  Check the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

Comment: I looked at the resampling, but how I see it, this sums up the timestamps per frequency set. I need a new page per month, but al the data still visible.